# Comparing two nominal-scale response distributions

Tags: r, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, categorical-data

I have data from an experiment that consist of nominal-scale responses that subjects made in two treatments (the treatments are between subjects, not repeated measures). I've provided my data in data frame and table form below. My goal is to compare the distributions of the responses in the two treatments - `t1` and `t2` - to see if they are significantly different from one another. I am not interested in differences among levels of the response variable (e.g., between response `a` and `c`).

I'm unsure how to approach this. My first thought was a Fisher exact test of the 8x2 contingency table (`tab` below), which yields: `p-value = 0.2102`. However, it seems that this tests whether the response variable is associated with the treatment variable as a whole, rather than testing for a difference between the treatments. Any suggestions for a better approach are most welcome.

```
# data frame with treatments and responses
df <- structure(list(id = 1:30, treatment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("t1", 
    "t2"), class = "factor"), response = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
    "treatment", "response"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), class = "data.frame")

# 8x2 contingency table
tab <- structure(c(12L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    response = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), treatment = c("t1", 
    "t2")), .Names = c("response", "treatment")), class = "table")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it seems that this tests whether the response variable is associated with the treatment variable as a whole, rather than testing for a difference between the treatments.

Those are the same thing. Each implies the other.

Comment: I kind of see what you mean after thinking about it more. Is there a way to get an idea of the magnitude of the difference between treatments, as opposed to just whether the difference is significant? An effect size?

Comment: There are many different ways the distribution of treatments can differ! What sort of effect do you want to measure?

Comment: The key thing is where the modal values lie. In the above example, the modes for treatment `t1` and `t2` are both at response `a`. I'm interested in how different the distributions are if say the mode of `t1` was `b` and `t2` was `g`.

Comment: Hm. Focus on that may be difficult when you have nominal data, or rather, it might well be easy, but I don't see an easy way to measure that.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps I'll calculate the odds for each response in `t1` vs `t2`. The change in the distribution of the odds over the responses may give some insight. Or perhaps even the difference between the odds for `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I often find that simple graphics convey much more information that a (necessarily low-dimensional) measure of effect size. For instance, I find `plot(tab)` already quite enlightening, although something else may, of course, be more appropriate to your research question.